# Need to make a copy of google spreadsheet and open copied spreadsheet in web page

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets-api

I have one google spreadsheet in my google account. I want to make a copy of the sheet in same account and open the copied new sheet in web page on clicking button in web page.

Kindly help to achieve this as i am new to this.
Able open the original sheet in webpage while clicking the button. But ineed to make a copy the sheet and open the copied sheet in webPage.

My code:

### Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function postYourInquiry() {
                var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
                ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1992ry0dpIjeNy_TQuB-W6fb2Nd7uST69AX_jY/edit#");
                ifrm.style.width = "10000px";
                ifrm.style.height = "2000px";
                document.body.appendChild(ifrm);

            }

            </script>



            <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core Muthu</a>.</p>
                <button id="postYourInquiry" onclick="postYourInquiry()">Get Inquiry details</button>
            </div >
```

Comment: Can someone help me on this..

Comment: Can someone help me to achieve this...

Comment: kindly help me out ....

Comment: Kindly check and  help me out. It would be great help.

Comment: can someone help me on this.